# How to replace the server name in the web application URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, deployment, central-administration, url

I have a server named sv002, and I have created an intranet web application at the root of this server. So currently I am able to access the web application using the following URL: - `http://sv002.`

But our client have asked to change the URL to be `http://compnayname.intra`. So I went to the SharePoint Central Administration > Alternative Access Mapping. Then I define the  URL (`http://compnayname.intra`) in the Intranet zone , while I left the Default zone as is (`http://sv002`).

I have the following two questions:-

1. Is there any missing steps inside SharePoint that I need to do , for changing the server name. as my next step is to inform the system admin about applying th mapping inside the server DNS?
2. How will SharePoint  recognize and decide which zone to use either the default or the Intranet,  when accessing the SharePoint site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't know which is the Internet, extranet or Intranet zone. When you choose the zone you are telling SharePoint that you will use different behaviour when authenticating users in the Web Application.
Each Web Application can have a maximum of 5 zones. The possible zones are:

- Default
- Intranet
- Internet
- Custom
- Extranet

When you use zones you have to extend the Web Application so different Web Applications (extended) point to a single Application Pool. So SharePoint recognize and decide which zone to use because you extend the WA and then, you write the targeted URL.

Extending the Web Application is maybe the step that you are missing

Comment: let take a simpler scenario , how can the clients access the web application using the required URL (http://compnayname.intra) instead of http://sv002 ?? regardless of having different zones? as in my case i do not have a real zones, the intranet is accessable within our network or from outside using VPN ?

Comment: First of all, you have to configure an Alternate Access Mapping in SharePoint. Then, create an alias in the DNS with the desired address (in this case compnayname.intra). Finally you have to add the binding in the IIS. This should work

Comment: thanks so inside the AAM , should i write the custom URL in the defualt zone only ?

Comment: It is not an issue of the zone. You could write the custom URL in whichever of the zones. If you are not planning to extend the WA you can just write the mapping in the default zone. You could consider the default zone as your intranet zone

Comment: i see, and what about the search content URL , should it be changed to the new URL www.compnayname.intra, or i can keep the old uRL http://sv002 ???

Comment: second point can i define the default zone uRL to be something such as www.compnayname.intra . i mean can i include the "www" in the URL ?

Comment: you can configure the search to the new URL because the AAM is configured and the search engine will know about this change. I am not sure if you can add www to your host names. Let me check it

Comment: if you leave sv002 in your search content URL then you can be sure crawl will index this server. However, when you modify it to companyname.intra, there can be some issues when multiple servers and loadbalancer are involved.

Comment: i leave the content source as is sv002 , and content are being crawled well (old contents and new contents).