# Masterpage conversion - causing javascript errors/masterpage breaks? when server name and internet url are different

Tags: 2013, master-page, custom-masterpage

JavaScript stops working and Masterpage seems to lose all styles.

There are 3 places where a converted .html Masterpage references the original URL/Domain the site was created in.

1. `<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>`
2. `<mso:HtmlDesignFromMaster msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignFromMaster>`
3. `<mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>`

This can cause problems if you have a development environment with a different URL/Server name than the production environment.

I've seen a reference to this in [one place](http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/discussions/449101): The 3rd comment references this problem and how it was fixed. Has anyone else encountered this?

At first, it seemed the Masterpage was breaking because somehow there was a duplicate meta tag added upon conversion.

```
 <!--CE: End Page Head Contents Snippet-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Once I removed the duplicate tag, the Masterpage worked again. But now, it's broken again and JavaScript doesn't work...

Any ideas on troubleshooting will be helpful

The suggested way to upload JavaScript files in SP Server 2013 is using the mapped network drive from design manager, yet, several people have mentioned there are different locations where JS files can be loaded and some continue to use 2007 and 2010 methods.

1. (2013) Using the [JSLink Method](http://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1.html)

   ```
   <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/assets/js/jquery.js" runat="server" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="True" />
   ```
2. (2010) Load to: [/_LAYOUTS/CustomScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91981/how-to-add-jquery-library-in-sharepoint2013) or [/_LAYOUTS/15/CustomScript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91981/how-to-add-jquery-library-in-sharepoint2013)
3. (2007/2010) 'Script Link' method [/_LAYOUTS/1033](http://tommdaly.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/scriptlink-vs-whats-the-difference/) StackExchange Question: [Unable to reference jQuery inside my master page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78025/unable-to-reference-jquery-inside-my-master-page)
4. (2010) 'Custom Action' method

   - http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions
   - http://blog.voyta.net/2010/09/12/referencing-javascript-files-using-customaction-in-sharepoint-2010-sandboxed-solutions/

I wonder that when the server name and internet url are different, if this would require using one of these different methods?

Comment: In my opinion, this post just doesn't provide enough information for anyone to help you. Javascript can stop working because of unhandled exception. Did you look at IE Developer Tools or Chrome Developer Tools while loading page? any errors? How do you build masterpage? Using Desginer Manager -> Editing associated .html file ?

Comment: Thanks - as mentioned in my post, I use Design Manager "...a converted .HTML Masterpage..." I use Firefox developer tools and there were no errors for the JavaScript because it didn't load in the browser... what other questions did you have?

Comment: This bounty was not helpful - can I have my points back?

Comment: You've just lost points? hmm..interesting. If you check .html file - (go to Edit properties on List Items) what values do ContentType and AssociatedFile columns have?

Comment: The points comment was directed at the sharepoint.stackexchange.com "points wizard" (it costs points to run a bounty)

Comment: When looking at edit properties for my home.html template I find content type 'Html Page Layout' and associated content type is 'Page Layout Content Types' and content type name 'Welcome Page'

Comment: I can't put a screenshot here or I would

Comment: ok nevermind - the javascript is within the masterpage - the content type is 'HTMl master page' and associated file is checkmarked

Comment: You are probably doing a Design Package and then "deploying" it to production environment? Try just Mapping network drive and then copy/paste .html/css/js - change Content Type on .html file

Comment: DN - no, I am using design manager. I'm not deploying it as a solution. I use the mapped network drive. What should the content type be??

Comment: Post/attach working version of masterpage/html/css/js so we can try.

Answer (score 1):

I would first check to see if the js and css script and link tags are present in the browser. Load your site in the browser and view source. Can you find valid tags that should be telling the browser to request the css and js files?

Next, use Fiddler or the net tab in Firebug and reload your page again. Are the css and js files actually being requested by the browser? I have to assume not, but if they are, now you need to figure out why they are not being used.

Still stuck? open up your HTML Master Page's associated .master Master Page in SPD. You can open this without problems, SP will just not let you save it. That is ok. What you are looking for is link, script and/or cssregistration tags within your .master that correspond to your link and script tags in your HTML Master Page. It may be that Design Manager is stripping your tags for some yet to be determined reason.

Let me know what else you find.

Comment: thanks for your input here. It was really nice to meet at you at SPSaturday San Diego! 
1. View source: Javascript file is not there
2. NET View in Firefox developer tools - Javascript file is not there.
3. .MASTER page view in SPDesigner not found for the Javascript file I've linked in the correspdonding HTML file
4. MASTER.HTML file - Javascript *IS* linked before </HEAD> tag

Comment: I am thinking that because the server name is different from the site url. The mapped network drive points to the site url. Is this anywhere in SP documentation?  [link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79424/how-to-replace-the-server-name-in-the-web-application-url)

Comment: Please note: I updated my question with different methods which are used to 1. Load JS in SP Server and 2. Link JS from masterpage or since 2013, HTML

Comment: Getting there...
http://www.wictorwilen.se/the-correct-way-to-execute-javascript-functions-in-sharepoint-2013-mds-enabled-sites
http://chuvash.eu/tag/minimal-download-strategy/
sharepointannoyances.wordpress.com/tag/scriptlink/
http://www.edinkapic.com/2013/09/how-to-enable-custom-javascript-on-mds.html
http://www.gsoft.com/en/blog/sharepoint-2013-developing-with-the-new-mds-feature